# webpack: upload sourceMaps to own server via api

Tags: webpack, npm-scripts

I'm trying to log web app errors to my node server but the client code is obfuscated and I need to deobfuscate it on the server.

The reason for that is I don't want to expose the source code to the web client.

So I need a way to setup webpack/npm scripts to accomplish the following:

1. during the build generate the sourcemaps (under "dist/" folder)
2. upload the sourcemaps to my server via api
3. delete the generated sourcemaps from the local "dist/" folder

While I know how to solve the 1 and 3 (using [this plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/delete-sourcemap-webpack-plugin)), I've already spent about two days trying to figure out how to accomplish the 2nd point.

Most of the articles I've found were related to 3rd-party services that specializes on collecting errors and their webpack plugins (I even tried to figure out how they do that from the source code but that would take me another few days as I can see).

I'm not looking to use any 3rd-party services like sentry etc, but since they can do it, I'm confident it's possible to upload the sourcemaps to my server in webpack, but so far no luck on accomplishing that. I also tried to research npm scripts but with the same result.

Any advices on how to accomplish that?

Maybe any existing plugins that I've missed?

Comment: Cant you just upload files after the build using idk express-fileupload?

Comment: Thanks @PetrAveryanov. I can see how this can be used to receive files on server side, but I guess I don't quite understand how to make use of it to actually send the file from the client side from within an npm script/webpack. Do you have any quick references on how to accomplish the upload as part of the build process?